# Blender file not opening

Tags: blend-files

I encountered an issue with a Blender project I was working on, where attempting to open it resulted in a gray screen with the Blender logo in the top left corner, followed by an eventual crash. I suspect the file's size may be the problem, as my PC struggled with its laggy performance during editing. I'm quite concerned that I may not be able to access the project again.
What are some possible solutions?

Comment: open a new blender. Then go to File > Append and from there, you could extract the meshes, shaders, collections and so

Comment: Omg it actually helped me TYSM!!